# for next loop brackets in javascript

Tags: javascript, curly-brackets

I recently found this bit of JavaScript code (which is fine functionally) but I noticed that they're were no brackets around the for next loop. I always thought you must include them for the code to function. Under what conditions can you omit the brackets and still get away with it? Functionally, that is, not aesthetically.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rbuttons.children.length; i++)
    if (rbuttons.children[i].value == true)
        return rbuttons.children[i].text;
```

Comment: If the brackets are not present then it takes immediate line to its for loop. So you have the one line of coding with in the looping or conditional statements then you can omit the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets are not mandatory for one statement only. Good practice but not mandatory

so

```
if (x) alert("x");
```

or

```
if (x) 
   alert("x");
```

will work

In your case

```
if (rbuttons.children[i].value == true) return rbuttons.children[i].text;
```

is one statement

Answer (score 1):

If no brackets 'for' and 'if' consider only next statement.that's why your code is running.give one more statement after for and check,your code will not work.

```
var y=2;
var x=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 x+=i;//inside loop
 y+=i;//not inside loop


if(y)
x=5;//work according to if condition
y=10;//not work according to if condition
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as with `if`. The **next statement** counts as member of the `for` loop.

```
for( var i = 0; i<10;i++)
console.log(i);
console.log("foo");
// prints 0-9 but "foo" only once
```

Since the `if` in your code has only the `return` statement bound to itself and the `if` itself is bound to the `for`, you can omit the braces for both in this snippet.

Sloppy and error-prone style and absolutely not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the brackets if you only have one statement.

```
if (someTest)
statement1;
statement2;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (someTest)
{
    statement1;
}
statement2;
```

Please note that it is considered best practice to **always include** the brackets.